# How can I reduce noise in my water pipes?

Tags: plumbing, water, noise-reduction, water-hammer, old-pipes

I have a 1941 ranch house with two floors (SFH turned into a non-conforming duplex) and the pipes are making a loud banging sound every day and night. (Day is less followed, less heard because I'm not around and not focused on it, and usually working with the radio.) When I do make note is at night. It happens 3-4 times a night. At all ends of the house (so sometimes it's loud, sometimes softer depending on how far from my bedroom).

I tried turning off the irrigation and that did nothing. I changed the flapper on both toilets. Nothing. I turned off the water main, and that made it all go away. Of course I can't do this every night (Although I wish I could). I don't have ice makers or dishwashers in either unit. Essentially nothing is happening from the human side (showers, toilet, etc.) but I still have this nightly noise.

My neighbors don't have irrigation (I asked). I do live near a water district pump station but they tell me it's not that. One time the noises stopped when the downstairs tenant was away for a week (but not completely).

I'm desperate for ideas or ways to solve this nightly disruption. Help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have baseboard water heating (aka hydronic heating). The copper pipes circulate boiling water around your house and heat your home.

The heating and cool-down cycle causes the metal to expand and contract which would be the culprit of the noise.

Comment: I have a furnace and forced air heating unfortunately, but it's a good point for another old house! Thank you.

Comment: @Larissa Is it a single bang or does the noise last for several seconds? What kind of plumbing do you have: copper, galvanized steel, or PEX?

Comment: It's typically 3-4 bangs (sounds just like someone grabbing a pipe and shaking it). I have mostly galvanized pipes with some copper.

Comment: @Larissa So do the pipes ever do this when you simply use water?

Comment: Nope. They do not make sounds in normal everyday use.

Comment: @Larissa Does it coincide with your water heater heating up water?

Comment: No, there is nothing going on in the house at all. Noises come 1am, 3am, 5am (not usually on the dot, but in those ranges and not every two hours, just random times, etc

Comment: Larissa: I think what @MonkeyZeus might be getting at is exactly what I think it might be as well.  Your water heater constantly heats water up to its set point, then shuts off and waits for the temp to drop below a certain threshold again before reheating it.  This happens a lot when you use hot water like shower/dishwasher, etc., but it also happens periodically (like every couple hours) when you're not using any water at all.  I suspect that the pipe banging is probably expansion/contraction from re-heating stale hot water.

Answer (score 0):

Water Hammer Arrestors.

[image: Image from plumbingsupply.com, no endorsement implied]

Or, if old-style with dead-end pipe sections doing the arresting, (likely for 1941 if they were installed at all) just shut off the water main, open all faucets and drain the water from the pipes, then close up and refill to replenish the air bubbles in the dead ends that slowly dissolve away.

Comment: I haven't truly done the air bubble clearing, my plumber poo poo'd the idea, but I will try this weekend. Thank you.

Comment: do I also need to clear water from outside hose spigots too?

Comment: Might as well. Main thing is having higher faucets open to let air in, and the lowest drain in the building open to let water out. But if you let most of the water out the outside faucets, that's less to put in a bucket inside if there's a lower drain inside.

Comment: So I did all of that yesterday, drained the house of water starting high and ending low. Then turned the water main back on and opened up everything starting low to high (and including outside spigots). I did two rounds to try and clear air. Went to bed last night and it was silent the entire night until 5:06am when banging happened, and then happened 3 more times in that single hour. It all came from basically the same spot, which is an area that also has the water heater and under my bedroom. You can get my frustration here. (I did not open up the pressure valve on the water heater.)

Comment: Pressure valve should not need to be opened, and often leaks if you do... So, you may not have dead-end hammer arrestors, in which case you may need to add hammer arrestors to the system. It's worth trying the drain step because you normally can't see them if you do have them, and sometimes they are there. If they are not there, you'll need to add them, which is obviously more work.

Comment: You lost me...what's the "drain step" that's worth trying? I did all the faucets and spigots yesterday. At the moment i don't have any hammer arrestors that I know of anywhere. My large water tank does have an expansion tank. I do have a pressure reducing valve at the entry point to the house, which may be faulty or need replacing. My pressure was low -- 40-60 pounds. My irrigation is faulty and needs to be replaced, but when I turned the water off there, I still had overnight noises. So I'm replacing them, but most likely not the problem.

Comment: Draining the water out of the pipes. Which you've done, without notable effect.

Answer (score 0):

If the noise stops when the other resident in the building is away (or at least significantly reduces), it's highly likely that it's this other person's water use that's causing the problem for you.

The fact that it didn't completely stop could be due to a leaking toilet, for example, so it continued even though the other tenant wasn't there.

If the problem is in the other apartment, then you can either knock on the door and politely ask for assistance in identifying the cause so you can both take it up with the landlord, or (especially of the other guy isn't particularly friendly) just go straight to the landlord and ask him to investigate.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan. I'm the owner. I changed the flapper on their toilet and noises continued.